# OAuthException: (#2) Failed to create any app request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, apprequests

I am using following code to send request from application to user. Everything was fine, but suddenly it stops to work and I get an error:
*OAuthException: (#2) Failed to create any app request*

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = $this->app_id;
$config['secret'] = $this->app_secret;
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$this->app_id}&client_secret={$this->app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials";
$token = file_get_contents($url);
$request = $facebook->api('/'.$id.'/apprequests', 'POST', array(
   'message' => $text,
   'access_token' => $token
  )
  );
```

Looks like token is valid, and I don't know where else can be the problem.

Comment: I don’t see you actually _using_ the token anywhere in your code …

Comment: Sorry, I've missed one line in example code `'access_token' => $token`(fixed), but original code is ok, mistake was only here in example. 
Buy the way, I get this error in Graph API Explorer also.
[screen](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59820811/oauthexeption.JPG)

Comment: The endpoint does _not_ return the token only, but a string in the form `access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`. So what you are passing as `access_token` parameter is not really an access token.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint does not return the token only, but a string in the form `access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

So what you are passing as `access_token` parameter is not really an access token – you’ll have to trim the `access_token=` first.

Comment: The one should add the following lines to the code above:
`$psevdo_token = file_get_contents($url);
$temp = explode('=', $psevdo_token);
$token = $temp[1];
`

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid app access_token to make the request to the API. The easiest way to create an app access_token is to use the app_id and secret. As the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) states:

> There is another method to make calls to the Graph API that doesn't
>   require using a generated app token. You can just pass your app id and
>   app secret as the access_token parameter when you make a call:
>
> `https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret`